# Build failed for ios after configuring branch.io throwing node_modules/react-native-branch/ios/Branch-SDK/Fabric/Fabric.h: No such file or directory

Tags: react-native, cocoapods, react-native-ios, google-fabric, branch.io

Excuse me if its a silly mistake but its my first project on mobile-development and react-native. I do have very less knowledge on mobile development environment configuration.

I am trying for branch integration on my project and After integration of branch.io build is failing for ios.

I have followed steps as mentioned in official page of react-native branch. 
[Installation of react-native-branch for pure react-native app](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-branch#pure-react-native-app-using-react-native-link)

I installed cocapods and did all the configuration as mentioned on 
[setup for Ios](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-branch#objective-c)

After which on running

```
react-native run-ios
```

i am having the error

```
PBXCp /Users/bibek/Desktop/canvas-mobile-app/node_modules/react-native-branch/ios/Branch-SDK/Fabric/Answers.h /Users/bibek/Desktop/canvas-mobile-app/ios/build/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/include/Branch/Answers.h (in target: RNBranch)
    cd /Users/bibek/Desktop/canvas-mobile-app/node_modules/react-native-branch/ios
    builtin-copy -exclude .DS_Store -exclude CVS -exclude .svn -exclude .git -exclude .hg -resolve-src-symlinks /Users/bibek/Desktop/canvas-mobile-app/node_modules/react-native-branch/ios/Branch-SDK/Fabric/Answers.h /Users/bibek/Desktop/canvas-mobile-app/ios/build/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/include/Branch

error: /Users/bibek/Desktop/canvas-mobile-app/node_modules/react-native-branch/ios/Branch-SDK/Fabric/Answers.h: No such file or directory


PBXCp /Users/{user_name}/Desktop/{Project_name}/node_modules/react-native-branch/ios/Branch-SDK/Fabric/ANSCompatibility.h /Users/{user_name}/Desktop/{Project_name}/ios/build/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/include/Branch/ANSCompatibility.h (in target: RNBranch)
    cd /Users/{user_name}/Desktop/{Project_name}/node_modules/react-native-branch/ios
    builtin-copy -exclude .DS_Store -exclude CVS -exclude .svn -exclude .git -exclude .hg -resolve-src-symlinks /Users/{user_name}/Desktop/{Project_name}/node_modules/react-native-branch/ios/Branch-SDK/Fabric/ANSCompatibility.h /Users/{user_name}/Desktop/{Project_name}/ios/build/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/include/Branch
error: /Users/{user_name}/Desktop/{Project_name}/node_modules/react-native-branch/ios/Branch-SDK/Fabric/ANSCompatibility.h: No such file or directory


PBXCp /Users/{user_name}/Desktop/{Project_name}/node_modules/react-native-branch/ios/Branch-SDK/Branch-SDK/BNCKeyChain.h /Users/{user_name}/Desktop/{Project_name}/ios/build/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/include/Branch/BNCKeyChain.h (in target: RNBranch)
    cd /Users/{user_name}/Desktop/{Project_name}/node_modules/react-native-branch/ios
    builtin-copy -exclude .DS_Store -exclude CVS -exclude .svn -exclude .git -exclude .hg -resolve-src-symlinks /Users/{user_name}/Desktop/{Project_name}/node_modules/react-native-branch/ios/Branch-SDK/Branch-SDK/BNCKeyChain.h /Users/{user_name}/Desktop/{Project_name}/ios/build/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/include/Branch

error: /Users/{user_name}/Desktop/{Project_name}/node_modules/react-native-branch/ios/Branch-SDK/Branch-SDK/BNCKeyChain.h: No such file or directory



PBXCp /Users/{user_name}/Desktop/{Project_name}/node_modules/react-native-branch/ios/Branch-SDK/Fabric/Fabric.h /Users/{user_name}/Desktop/{Project_name}/ios/build/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/include/Branch/Fabric.h (in target: RNBranch)
    cd /Users/{user_name}/Desktop/{Project_name}/node_modules/react-native-branch/ios
    builtin-copy -exclude .DS_Store -exclude CVS -exclude .svn -exclude .git -exclude .hg -resolve-src-symlinks /Users/{user_name}/Desktop/{Project_name}/node_modules/react-native-branch/ios/Branch-SDK/Fabric/Fabric.h /Users/{user_name}/Desktop/{Project_name}/ios/build/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/include/Branch

error: /Users/{user_name}/Desktop/{Project_name}/node_modules/react-native-branch/ios/Branch-SDK/Fabric/Fabric.h: No such file or directory


** BUILD FAILED **


The following build commands failed:

    PBXCp /Users/{user_name}/Desktop/{Project_name}/node_modules/react-native-branch/ios/Branch-SDK/Fabric/Answers.h /Users/{user_name}/Desktop/{Project_name}/ios/build/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/include/Branch/Answers.h
    PBXCp /Users/{user_name}/Desktop/{Project_name}/node_modules/react-native-branch/ios/Branch-SDK/Fabric/ANSCompatibility.h /Users/{user_name}/Desktop/{Project_name}/ios/build/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/include/Branch/ANSCompatibility.h
    PBXCp /Users/{user_name}/Desktop/{Project_name}/node_modules/react-native-branch/ios/Branch-SDK/Branch-SDK/BNCKeyChain.h /Users/{user_name}/Desktop/{Project_name}/ios/build/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/include/Branch/BNCKeyChain.h
    PBXCp /Users/{user_name}/Desktop/{Project_name}/node_modules/react-native-branch/ios/Branch-SDK/Fabric/Fabric.h /Users/{user_name}/Desktop/{Project_name}/ios/build/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/include/Branch/Fabric.h
(4 failures)
```

Comment: might be due to improper linking, check [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-branch#pure-react-native-app-using-react-native-link)

Comment: Looking at logs it seems like sdk and path is not set accordingly. Can you make sure that SDK path and app path is same and try building the project.

Answer (score 1):

For me i was using npm as package manager and used yarn to just install this package only.

I solved it by removing all npm packages and finally installing it with yarn and perform a fresh linking. It worked.